# Java Toggle between Hiding and Showing Exceptions

Tags: netbeans, exception, java-8

My IDE is NetBeans I want to toggle between showing exceptions and silently catching them between builds to do this I use a public static field and test it across the application classes . What is the best approach to do this ?

Comment: Can you add some example code for what you are trying to do?